# Solve the limit without using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{8(\frac 12 + x)^8-8(\frac 12)^8}{x}$

My attempt at the problem: I tried using substitution, $h = \frac 12 +x$, but I ended up where I began. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the definition $f'(x) \equiv \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$?

Comment: How would the definition be helpful in this instance?

Comment: As Anurag A said the limit is the derivative at that point

Comment: I do not think I am allowed to use the derivative definition, but I may get it geometrically (graphically) or analytically.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Recall 
$$f'(a)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(a+x)-f(a)}{x}.$$

So this limit is the derivative of $f(t)=8t^8$ at $t=1/2$.

Comment: This is almost certainly the point of this particular exercise.

Comment: Agreed, and, from there, how does one proceed to evaluate using the limit definition?

Comment: @user237426 since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{8(\frac 12 + x)^8-8(\frac 12)^8}{x}=\frac{d}{dt}(8t^8)\Big|_{t=1/2}$, therefore all you need to do is compute the derivative of $f(t)=8t^8$ at $t=1/2$. Since the derivative is $f'(t)=64t^7$, therefore at $t=1/2$.....

Comment: I do not think we're allowed to use to Power Rule.

Comment: @user237426 firstly ascertain for sure what things you can use. If you cannot use the power rule then I think David Quinn's answer would be the one that you can use. But if you cannot use binomial also then I don't know what to suggest you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial theorem on the first term. The numerical term cancels, and the only term not containing an $x$ is $8\times8(\frac 12)^7,$which must be the limit as $x\rightarrow0$

Comment: what happens to the denominator, though?

Comment: It cancels with all the $x$'s in the numerator

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Try to divide both, numerator and denominator by $x$. Keep in mind that $1/x$ goes to infinity as $x$ goes to zero.

*(I really like Anurag's answer, using the definition of the derivative is a really good method for this particular limit)*

Comment: How does dividing both the numerator and denominator by $x^8$ work out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use derivatives, then use algebra:
\begin{align}
a^8-b^8
&=(a^4-b^4)(a^4+b^4)\\
&=(a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)\\
&=(a-b)(a+b)(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)
\end{align}
In your case $a=\frac{1}{2}+x$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$, so you get
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{8(\frac 12 + x)^8-8(\frac 12)^8}{x}
&=\lim_{x\to0}
8\frac{
  x
  \Bigl(\frac{1}{2}+x+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)
  \Bigl((\frac{1}{2}+x)^2+\frac{1}{4}\Bigr)
  \Bigl((\frac{1}{2}+x)^4+\frac{1}{16}\Bigr)
}{x}\\[6px]
&=\lim_{x\to0}
  8(x+1)
  \Bigl((\tfrac{1}{2}+x)^2+\tfrac{1}{4}\Bigr)
  \Bigl((\tfrac{1}{2}+x)^4+\tfrac{1}{16}\Bigr)
\end{align}
Now you can plug in $x=0$.